# Is there an iOS email client that does IMAP properly?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, mail.app, imap

I specifically am looking for an iOS email client that supports IMAP's ability to delete messages "in place", i.e. without moving them to some "trash" folder.  I would want to be able to view deleted messages appropriately marked (or greyed out) in their original folder, with a separate option to expunge either a single message or all deleted messages in a folder.

I can do all these things with the default Mail.app on OS X, so it's especially frustrating that Apple doesn't offer equivalent support on iOS.  Does anyone know of another iOS email client that does this right?

And for extra credit, I'd love to have these features too:

- True Junk mail filtering
- Ability to subscribe/unsubscribe from IMAP folders

Comment: Have you tried Sparrow by Google?

Comment: Yes I have tried Sparrow.  Like the others I've tried, it insists on moving messages to a Trash folder rather then deleting them in place.

Comment: Well to delete these items, as a developer we need to "FLAG" these message as trash then update the object. So we just change the email status from seen to trash. I am currently developing an email client app and will keep this in mind. Thanks